# upgrading from log4j 1.2.17 to log4j 2

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have upgrade from log4j-1.2.17 to log4j-2 with needed code changes and then removed log4j and deployed log4j2. service not starting, hence, logs not generating, where I need check

Comment: Mahesh, you need to describe in detail what you did. What code changes are you referring to? If your application does not start there is certainly an error message in the logs.

Comment: Activemq  5.15.9  with log4j.properties running in my origination. I want to upgrade from log4j to lo4j2. I have download latest log4j2.properties file and modified with my application code, hence, removed log4j and added log4j2.properites along with this two jars (log4j-api-2.17.1, log4j-core-2.17.1) on respective folders and then stopped service.  while starting service its not starting, even logs also not generating. What I have to check ? Please let me know how to upgrade from lo4j to log4j2.

Comment: please reply Piotr

Comment: Log4j 1.x and Log4j2 are two separate projects binary incompatible. Did you check the [migration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)?